# Redirection In index.php page in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

Iam developing a site in codeigniter.This is my url `http://myserver.net/visio/UBwXo`.
Here h`ttp://myserver.net/visio/` is my base_url.

After `/visio/` here have a variable.When there have any value after /visio/ then i wantto take the corresponding url from database to this value.

That means in my database,

UBwXo => "****any url******"

jshom => "****any url******"

So when getting value after /visio/ i want to take the corresponding url from databse and redirect it in to that url without using htaccess.

I want to done this redirection process in index.php page of root folder.

Is this possible?

The orginal url for `http://myserver.net/visio/UBwXo` like `myserver.net/visio/index.php/admin/index/UBwXo`

the default controller is `admin`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, create redirect.php file in the controllers folder (*application/controllers*) and add this code to this file:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Redirect extends CI_Controller
{

    /**
     * Method to redirect from an alias to a full URL
     */
    public function index()
    {

    $alias = $this->uri->segment(1);

    $this->db->select('url');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('links', array('alias' => $alias), 1, 0);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        redirect($row->url, 'refresh', 301);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry, alias '$alias' not found";
    }
    }

}
```

Then create table in your database. Your table must be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alias` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `alias` (`alias`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

After that, set default controller value to the *redirect class*.
Open *application/config/routes.php*. Find `$route['default_controller']` , then set `redirect` as a value to this variable, like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "redirect";
```

Then enjoy life ;)

**EDIT:**

I had forgotten to mention URI routing in `config/routes.php` for redirecting:

```
$route[':any'] = "redirect/index/$1";
```

Comment: When i taking the url like this 'http://myserver.net/visio/UBwXo' I again get the same error 404 found. But 'http://myserver.net/visio/' using this link i got 'Sorry, alias '' not found' .What is the need of the above table links ?There have no rows in that table

Answer (score 0):

Your best resource here will be the CodeIgniter guides, specifically the page on [Controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html).  The section on [Remapping Function calls](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) should be exactly what you need in this case.

Since the default behavior is to look for a controller method with the name of the first segment after the base url, we need to change this to pass it as an argument to some function.  Your controller might look something like this:

```
class Shortener extends CI_Controller {

     private function shorten( $token ){
         // Find the URL that belongs to the token and redirect
     }

     public function _remap( $method, $params = array() ) {

         // Catch other controller methods, pulled from the CodeIgniter docs
         if ( method_exists( $this, $method ) ) {
             return call_user_func_array( array( $this, $method ), $params );
         }

         $this->shorten( $method );

     }
}
```

Comment: but after this http://rapidsurfing.net/visio/ have a passing value not a controller name.The orginal url for this like http://rapidsurfing.net/visio/index.php/admin/index/UBwXo

Comment: the default controller is admin

Comment: @KichuUser - I'm not really sure what you're asking.